# django manage.py runserver error

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to make my first django project, startproject runs fine but when i try runserver this is the traceback error i get :

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\f orms.py", line 269, in SetPasswordForm
     help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())     
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 85, in password_validators_help_text_html
     help_texts = password_validators_help_texts(password_validators)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 74, in password_validators_help_texts
     password_validators = get_default_password_validators()  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\utils\lru_cach e.py", line 101, in wrapper
     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\p assword_validation.py", line 21, in get_default_password_validators
     return get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\p assword_validation.py", line 32, in get_password_validators
     validators.append(klass(**validator.get('OPTIONS', {})))  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\p assword_validation.py", line 164, in __init__
     with open(password_list_path) as f: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages \\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\\django\\contrib\\auth\\common-passwords.txt.gz'
```

i'm at my wits end here, please help

Comment: Django 1.9 is not released. Especially as you are a beginner, you should be using the latest released version, 1.8.

Comment: You should use the stable Django as  @DanielRoseman Suggests. The bleading edge code doesn't supply the "common-passwords.txt.gz", if you want you can suppress this by removing the password validation from the settings.py file (`AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = []`). Check this out - https://github.com/django/django/blob/8b1f39a727be91aab40bdb37235718ed63ae1d50/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py#L88

Comment: thank you @DanielRoseman i have reinstalled version 1.8 and seems to be working just fine oh and thanks for editing my question too

Answer (score 0):

Your django 1.9 installation is misssing [common-passwords.txt.gz](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/cracklib/common-passwords.txt.gz/5e35a78582c233f8b703f1dabf264788/) file.

Try to install `pip install django-password-validation` that seems to be required by this version. Or just put the file manually to `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\`

Comment: i had tried that initially but reinstalling v. 1.8 worked for me